# how to get github work tree or project structure

Tags: flutter, dart, github

I have uploaded a project in github. is there a way to get this project tree (structure) from github or anywhere else?
I want to get something like this (I want this text shown below or something like it to be generated from project). I got the text from [here](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterinfinitelisttutorial):

```
├── lib
|   ├── posts
│   │   ├── bloc
│   │   │   └── post_bloc.dart
|   |   |   └── post_event.dart
|   |   |   └── post_state.dart
|   |   └── models
|   |   |   └── models.dart*
|   |   |   └── post.dart
│   │   └── view
│   │   |   ├── posts_page.dart
│   │   |   └── posts_list.dart
|   |   |   └── view.dart*
|   |   └── widgets
|   |   |   └── bottom_loader.dart
|   |   |   └── post_list_item.dart
|   |   |   └── widgets.dart*
│   │   ├── posts.dart*
│   ├── app.dart
│   ├── simple_bloc_observer.dart
│   └── main.dart
├── pubspec.lock
├── pubspec.yaml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tree listing you are talking about can be done in many ways, The Two ways I know are

1. Using Tree Command

If you are in Unix or Windows based operating system just open a terminal in your lib directly or `cd` to it. That is if you are using VS Code simply open terminal and use `cd lib` after that just type `tree` you will get the listing and copy those.

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tree

for additional flags.

2. You can use tree generators online less preferable

One that I got is : https://ascii-tree-generator.com/

Comment: But how can show files like `post_bloc.dart` as question tree. Using `tree` command.